# How to use a stub image until the image from web loads?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have listbox and a data template for it. The listbox and the items in it are binded to a list.

One item in the listbox template is Image and its source is from web, since the source is from web it takes some time to load.

Can i use a alternate image until it loads. I was trying to have some default image near biding, and alternate way for binding programatically, binding each item one by one in a loop.

But these ideas no one have used.
If you have any idea on this please share.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use FallBackValue and/or TargetNullValue for an Image element binding. Here are two resources that you might find useful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx

so it will look like that:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath, FallbackValue=somelocalpathforimage, TargetNullValue=somelocalpathforimage}" />
```

Comment: I have tried this, but looks like some other thing is also missing. Should i need to change the property of the FallbackValue image resource?

Comment: can you verify that the path for an image, which you set as a FallBackValue and TargetNullValue works? (you can do it by setting it directly as a Image Source property).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the image use a Grid with 2 images, the stub image and the real image. These two images will be shown one on another in layers, so the stub will be visible exactly until the real one loads.

Quick, working and dirty trick :)